# csvモードで選択したセルの合計を表示する方法

Tags: csv, emeditor

CSVモードで、シフトキーと矢印キー（カーソルキー）で複数のセル（数字が入っている）を反転（選択）した際、選択セルの合計を表示するようなことはできるのでしょうか？

やり方があれば教えて頂けますか。

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor v20.0.909 以上に更新されていることを確認してから、CSV 文書を開き、合計したい数のセルをすべて選択してから、[マクロ] ツール バーの Σ (合計) ボタンをクリックしてください。

[image: EmEditor 合計マクロ]

Comment: Version 20.0.4を使っています。

Comment: 最新だと思うのですが、v20.0.909以上に更新するにはどうしたら良いですか？
自分の環境で同じようなことをすると「-nan(ind)」と表示されました。

Comment: インストーラー版をお使いの場合、自動的に最新のベータ版に更新するには、[ヘルプ] メニューの [更新チャネルの選択] を選択し、[ベータ版と公式リリースの両方] を選択してください。https://support.emeditor.com/ja/downloads からもダウンロードしていただけます。

Comment: v20.0.910にバージョンアップしました。
返信頂いたことができております。ありがとうございます。
Σ(合計)のボタンをクリックする代わりに、キーボードに登録できたりしますか？

Comment: どのようなコマンドやマクロでもキーボード ショートカットに設定できます。画面図で詳しく示したいので、別の質問として書いていただけると幸いです。なお、さきほど、v20.1.0 正式版を公開いたしましたので、通常の方法で更新していただけます。

Comment: v20.1.0をダウンロードしてみます。
またショートカットの件、別の質問に登録します。
いろいろありがとうございました。